# Need clarification on the mechanics of calling a non-object function from an object

Tags: objective-c

Note: *this is for self edification.*

**Scenarios:** 
I create an Objective-C object and within it I call a standard C function.

**Scenario #1:** (C function *outside* an ObjC object):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

void SayHello() {
    int x = 12345;
    char *y = "Greetings";

    printf("%s: The value of x: %i", y, x);
}

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    SayHello();
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


@end
```

**Scenario #2:** (C function *within* an ObjC object):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

void SayHello() {
    int x = 12345;
    char *y = "Greetings";

    printf("%s: The value of x: %i", y, x);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    SayHello();
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


@end
```

**Question:** 
Do the two scenarios differ other than scope?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: The assumption about the "location" of the function is incorrect; it has no data (unlike an object) to be stored in the heap *or* on the stack.

Comment: Scenario 1 and 2 are the same. The location of `SayHello` can be anywhere in the file. It makes no difference. There's no such concept as a C function being within or outside an Objective-C class.

Comment: Replaced images with code.   rmaddy just answered my question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference, and not even the scope changes. ObjC lets you call visible C functions from within ObjC methods, and you can define those functions anywhere you want; they are immune to the ObjC scoping syntax and are always "global" in this sense.

I have seen C functions defined deliberately "inside" or "outside" of an ObjC class implementation as a stylistic way of indicating that the function is (or is not) used "privately" by one class. But the actual scope won't change.

If you want that C function to be invisible outside the `.m` file, use the `static` keyword in its declaration which limits its actual scope to that compilation unit (this is a C thing, not an ObjC thing).